# How to get Recordings associated with Microsoft Teams Meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am saving scheduled meeting in MS teams using me/events in MS Graph API v1.0 . This gives more options to specify details and also creates meeting on the user calendar and sends invite to attendees.
After saving , i get the join url to join meeting which i display in my application.

I want to get the recordings associated with meeting . After reading ,i tried to implement subscription on
/communication/callrecording Api. This notifies me with all the recording i.e Peer-Peer and Meetings for my organization. My task is to identify the meetings that were created by me for which i have the MeetingId and JoinUrl.

```
AAMkADUxNGY3YzE1LTA5ODAtNGNkNC1iODExLWM2NjY4MmVjYjM2YQBGAAAAAAChpaW4Sb6bToDnSEr1OGm7BwBSAtUAib0LQYlgy--cQQ7dAAAAAAE**********

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_YTRmM2Q4MzMtNTE1Ni00MTE4LWEzNTEtMDkzZGYxMGM3ZGQ5%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%**************%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22**************%22%7d
```

Sample notification

```json
{
    "value": [
        {
            "subscriptionId": "51c2e49d-daf5-4ff5-86df-c18*****",
            "clientState": "abc123",
            "changeType": "created",
            "resource": "communications/callRecords/434012cf-******",
            "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2021-01-14T03:08:45.7350424-08:00",
            "resourceData": {
                "oDataType": "#microsoft.graph.callrecord",
                "oDataId": "communications/callRecords/434012cf-3526-4103-9e92-******",
                "id": "434012cf-3526-******"
            },
            "tenantId": "********"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get recording for a meeting using notification or any other method using the meetingid that i get after saving a meeting ?

Comment: Adding the answer below. Please go ahead, accept the answer and upvote it. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently You cannot record the meeting using the Graph API, This is by design. Could you please You can get the call recording using Get Call record API. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Answer (score 0):

I know its in the [Roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=25197). Currently it is not possible to get the
meeting recording through Graph API. It's in their backlog:)